# NSStackView edgeInsets gets ignored

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsstackview

Using `edgeInsets` on `NSStackView` is ignored by Interface Builder and when running the app.

[image: NSStackView edgeInsets not working]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSStackView` default hugging priority is 250. The `edgeInsets` is only enforced when the **hugging priority** is **500 or higher**.

[image: NSStackView edgeInsets hugging priority]

**Important:** `NSStackView` has a hugging priority and a **content** hugging priority which are not the same.

[image: NSStackView hugging priority and a content hugging priority]

Comment: Is it just me or is the logic backwards here? I mean, you tell it to hug it's contents _more_, by upping the value from 250 to 500, and then it hugs them _less_, by respecting the edge insets. Weird, right? I'm also seeing something odd where I set only the bottom edge inset, but it uses that value for the top too. I may need to ask another question about that.